# When a link is clicked, a value is retrieved from the table and displayed on a Webform field

Tags: 7, nodes, database, webforms

I have created a basic page with two buttons, "Yes" and "No". When the "Yes" button is clicked, it is directed to the webform.

Aim: When the webform appears, it displays a value from the table into a field.

**Database**

- Table name: Room
- Field: Room
- Data: Training Room

**The Basic Page**

[image: Basic page appearance]

**The Webform**

[image: The Lettable Booking Form]

I created a module for this functionality:

**test_presave.info**

```
name = "Test presave"

description = "Retrieving data from table"

core = 7.x

package = Test
```

**test_presave.module**

```
/*

*Implements hook_node_presave()

*/

function test_presave_node_presave($node)

{

    $accessnode=$node->nid;

    if($accessnode==20)//Lettable Room Booking webform

    {

        $result=$db_query("SELECT Room FROM {Room} WHERE Room =:ln",array(':ln'=>'Training Room'))->fetchCol();

        $node->webform['components'][1]['value']=$result;

    }

}
```

Am I using the correct hook?

Do I have to use the node api or the webform api?

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Rather do this:

Alter the button link to include a parameter:

```
<a href="./lettable-room-booking?captured=true">Yes</a>
```

In [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x), check for the parameter and set the default value(s):

```
function test_presave_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    // dpm($form_id); // uncomment to get $form_id
    // dpm($form); // uncomment to get $form
    if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_2') { // use dpm($form_id) to get your form id
        $param = drupal_get_query_parameters();
        if (isset($param['captured']) && $param['captured'] == "true")
        {
            $result = ...
            if ($result) {
                $form['submitted']['room']['#default_value'] = $result; // use dpm($form) to get your room field
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is 'room'? Is it the name or the form_key?

Comment: It is the form field name that webform gave my room field. Yours might be different. Use dpm($form['submitted']) to inspect

Comment: PS. to get dmp() you need [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) installed